# Unity2.0 - Is it possible to specify assemblies and namespaces for type lookup programatically?

Tags: unity-container, xml-configuration

I am using Unity2 with XML configuration. It has the neat feature to specify namespaces and assemblies in the XML config for which automatic type lookup is performed, so that you do not need to always specify full name or create an alias.

Is it possible to specify assemblies and namespaces for the automatic type lookup programatically, without them being explicitly listed in the XML configuration? My goal is to simplify the XML configuration for my application's administrators. Types from two or three namespaces will almost always be used in the container registrations, so I would like these namespaces to be included in the lookup automatically.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing built in explicitly to support this.

An option would require a few more steps in your code. instead of just calling container.LoadConfiguration(), you'd instead explicitly grab the configuration section:

```
var section = (UnityConfigurationSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("unity");
```

Then, you'd go into the Namespaces or Assemblies properties on the section, and add new NamespaceElement or AssemblyElement objects pointing at the "standard" namespaces and assemblies. *Then* you apply the updated configuration section to the container. Something like this:

```
section.Namespaces.Add(new NamespaceElement() { Name = "my.standard.namespace" });
container.LoadConfiguration(section);
```

I haven't actually tried this, :-), but it should work.

Comment: I have already tried this exact approach, but unfortunately an exception is thrown when calling the Add() method. It says the configuration is read-only.

Comment: Well, darn, sorry about that.